# Custom Taxonomy Select Menu: Setting default option value?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, dropdown, select

I'm creating a series of select drop down menus that pull data from various taxonomies. I got this PHP script working for a WooCommerce attribute of color:

```
function get_color_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
    $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
    $output ="<select onChange='window.location.href=this.value'>";
    foreach($myterms as $term){
        $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
        $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
        $term_slug=$term->slug;
        $term_name =$term->name;
        $link = $root_url.'/'.$term_taxonomy.'/'.$term_slug;
        $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
    }
     $output .="</select>";
return $output;
}

$taxonomies = array('pa_color');
$args = array('orderby'=>'name','order'=>'ASC','hide_empty'=>true);
echo get_color_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);
```

Great. This is what I want. But it's missing something. A default value.

In my case, I want it to be  something that doesn't even appear in the database. Something like 'Shop by Color -->' since if it just has the first value, nobody is going to know what it is and what to do. No good.

So is there some kind of statement I can incorporate to add this one line of code to my select menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an extra  line before your for loop. For example:

```
function get_color_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
    $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
    $output ="<select onChange='window.location.href=this.value'>";
    $output .= "<option value='default'>Shop by Color --></option>";
    foreach($myterms as $term){
        $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
        $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
        $term_slug=$term->slug;
        $term_name =$term->name;
        $link = $root_url.'/'.$term_taxonomy.'/'.$term_slug;
        $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
    }
    $output .="</select>"; return $output;
}

$taxonomies = array('pa_color');
$args = array('orderby'=>'name','order'=>'ASC','hide_empty'=>true);
echo get_color_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);
```

You can always check to see if the return value is "default" to see if the select wasn't set.

Comment: That's it. I thought it might be something along those lines, but I just wasn't sure. Thanks.